# cookie gets deleted from another page?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have a strange case with my cookies.

On my overview.php i set

```
setcookie('threads_more','1',time()+3600,"/");
```

If the user gets back to index I delete the cookie with

```
setcookie('threads_more','1',time()-3600,"/");
```

But the cookie gets also deleted if I browse to other pages in this directory although there is no setcookie. Its like the setcookie command from index.php gets executed on every page in this directory. On pages in another directory the cookie stays alive. If I remove the deletecookie command on index.php it works fine.

Anyone an Idea?

Thanks a lot!
Kornel

Comment: May be you have included `index.php` in other files because of that this happens. Show code of your other files where it is deleted.

Comment: What about the cookie path? I think "/" means the entire domain. So you are deleting a cookie from the entire domain i.e. yoursite.com

Comment: `/` means "the entire domain". If you want to specify a single page only, you have to build your own logic (save the page in the name?)

Answer (score 0):

Try
A. Remove. "/"   the domain setting when setting cookies.
B. Check ode if you are setting cookies with blank node.

Idea is use default domain.

Another thing you should check, if you are using port 80.